# Google cloud storage image public link to img src

Tags: javascript, image, google-cloud-storage, src

Hi I have looked into related questions, but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer. I would like to serve public links from google cloud storage on my website, but they are only available as download links. I am unable to place them as img src to load them. I cannot download the image async from my webpage js because of CORS. Is there a workaround? I was wondering whether I could asynchronously define them as download links initially and force onclick to download them then use file reader to get the blob to use as img src.

UPDATE : I figured out that there was a Chromium issue. I used Firefox with CORS_Everywhere and the requests works. Once my website is live, will I have the same issue for the images? OR is it that CORS just doesn't accept localhost? OR is it browser dependent?

Thanks,
timecatcher

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. It sounds like you'd like to display images in an `<img>` tag where the source is in GCS. You shouldn't need any sort of CORS policy or Javascript trickery for that, so I may misunderstand your question.

To include GCS images on a website, make sure the image is publicly visible, then just include an image tag like this: `<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME" />`.

Edit with answer from the comments:

If you upload an object without specifying a Content-Type, GCS defaults to a generic "application/octet-stream." Web browsers generally default to saving `application/octet-stream` responses. Make sure JPEG images have the Content-Type "image/jpeg" if you want to serve them via the web.

One more caveat:

There is another  path using the `https://storage.cloud.google.com/` path, but that one is for users authenticating with their own account's Google cookies, and you generally don't wan to rely on that when serving public content. Use `https://storage.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I wish it was that easy. all the links created from my cloud storage account are media downloadable links not img src links one would expect.
Here is an example link : 
http://storage.googleapis.com/santex-1101.appspot.com/libertyCotton2.jpg

Comment: Ah! You have a different problem. GCS does not make assumptions about the Content-Type of the objects being uploaded, and this particular object has the default Content-Type of "application/octet-stream". Web browsers don't know how to render that, so they download it instead. Change the contentType of the object to "image/jpeg" and it should work fine.

Comment: Google cloud provides link `https://storage.cloud.google.com/BUCKET/path/to/image.jpg`, but correct link is `https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/path/to/image.jpg`... killed 4 hours of time...
Thanks man, your answer gave me an idea

Comment: Live saver @OlegReym

Comment: @OlegReym, you saved my 4h. Thank you. I suggest that Brandon should add this as part of his answer.

Comment: I have this URL but getting access denied there is any permission required.
https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET/Artboard_4.png

 Getting this error: 
 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.

Comment: @OlegReym worked perfectly fine for me. thanks a ton

Comment: @OlegReym You Legend !!